# How can you create a container for some JSON data in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have the following Json data in the variable `jsonstuff`

```
jsonstuff = [{sitekey: 1, sitename: "Google"}, {sitekey:2, sitename: "Apple"}, {sitekey: 3, sitename: "Microsoft"}]
```

But I wanted to encapsulate this data in a container called `appData` so the final result would be

```
jsonstuff = {appData: [{sitekey: 1, sitename: "Google"}, {sitekey:2, sitename: "Apple"}, {sitekey: 3, sitename: "Microsoft"}]}
```

Is there a quick way to do this with straightforward code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do

```dart
final jsonStuff = [
  {"sitekey": 1, "sitename": "Google"},
  {"sitekey": 2, "sitename": "Apple"},
  {"sitekey": 3, "sitename": "Microsoft"},
];  // List<Map<String, dynamic>>

final jsonStuff2 = {
  "appData": jsonStuff
};  // Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonStuff = [{sitekey: 1, sitename: "Google"}, {sitekey:2, sitename: "Apple"}, {sitekey: 3, sitename: "Microsoft"}]
```

Change it to -

```
final jsonStuff2 = {"appData": jsonStuff}
```